# Bug extracting content from an Iframe using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm uploading some files in the same page using the Iframe technique. I'm extracting the content from the IFrame. Everything is ok for the first submission, but when I make a second submission I got an extra line in the console log, and for the third submission I got 2 extra lines...

What I got in the Firebug console is:

```
-
name_1
+
-
name_2
+
name_2
+
```

What is my error?

```
<script>
window.onload=init;

function init() {
  $('#file_upload_form').submit( function() 
  {
     document.getElementById('file_upload_form').target = 'upload_target'; 

     $('#upload_target').load(function()
     {
         console.log ( $('#upload_target').contents().find('#response').html() );
         console.log ( "+" );               
     });
     console.log ( "_" );

  });
}

</script>
```

Comment: what is the `iframe technique`?

Comment: this one http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are adding an additional load handler every time you submit the form.  Try removing this:

```
$('#upload_target').load(function()
     {
         console.log ( $('#upload_target').contents().find('#response').html() );
         console.log ( "+" );               
     });
```

from the submit handler and just put it outside the submit handler.

Comment: I did it, but I don't know now how to extract the info from the iframe. I put the code below. Is that what you suggested?

<script>
window.onload=init;
$('#upload_target').load(function()
{
   console.log ( $('#upload_target').contents().find('#response').html() );
   console.log ( "+" );               
});

function init() {
  $('#file_upload_form').submit( function() 
  {
     document.getElementById('file_upload_form').target = 'upload_target'; 
     console.log ( "_" );

  });
}

</script>

Comment: put it inside init but outside of submit.